# pop a specific route with result in auto route flutter

Tags: flutter, android-activity, flutter-navigation

I'm using [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) as my app's navigation system. I need to do something like the `finish()` function in android activity which closes the current activity that it's being called from. How can I achieve this in flutter?

Comment: Page from where you are navigating
Use var result = await router.push<bool>(YourRoute());
print('RESULT ${result}');

Page from where you need data:

context.router.pop('Data 123');

output: Data 123

Comment: @iamnabink this way the topmost route will be popped with the provided result. I need the previously pushed route to be popped with the result.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer the case as of now **7.8.2**
The returned type is defined on the Routepage annotation

[image]

So define it this way

```dart
@RoutePage<AirtimeTransaction>()
```

Comment: since pop is deprecated now, how should I return the result to the previous screen?

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/432#issuecomment-831263774):

---

In your router config specify which data type is returned.
e.g.: (here a Set is returned)

```
AutoRoute<Set<User>>(
  page: UserSelectPage,
),
```

In your Page, you have to pop the values:

```
onPressed: () async {
  await AutoRouter.of(context).pop(yourValues);
},
```

Then in your code you can call this to push the page and work with the return value.

```
            onPressed: () async {
              final Set<User>? users = await AutoRouter.of(context)
                  .push<Set<User>>(UserSelectPageRoute());
              if (users != null) {
                await doOtherStuffWithYourNewData(users);
              }
            }
```

Comment: This way the topmost route will be popped with the provided result. I need the previously pushed route to be popped with the result. Consider following situation: 1)page 1 is in the stack 2)push page 2 and await for result 3) push page 3 4)how to pop page 2 with some result whilst page 3 is still in the stack?

Comment: Easiest option would be to call `popUntil` method [link to docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/auto_route/latest/auto_route/StackRouter/popUntil.html), but then I think you could not get any specific value returned. Try it out anyways.
Other option is if you can "chain" the `pop`s. So, wait for the pop from screen#3 to screen#2, and then do a pop from screen#2 to screen#1 - just like I showed above with the `await AutoRouter.of(context).push(...)`.